# Twiiter Bootstrap Modal is not closing when click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im using agency theme from boostrap but i customised the size of it but when click outside of it its not closing even the normal modal from bootstrap is not closing, (sometimes it close sometimes its note) ill show my bootstrap modal below:

```
          <p class="buttonp ">    <a href="#portfolioModal" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">
Click for more info </a></p>               
</div>

                               <!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
                        <div id="portfolioModal" class="modal fade portfolio-modal"   tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolioModal"  aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                               <!-- <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <div class="lr">
                                        <div class="rl">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip iscing elit. Suspendisse laoreet est nunc. Na </p>
                                                                                  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip iscing elit. Suspendisse laoreet est nunc. Na </p>
              </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- -->
```

Comment: The modal code is ok. Can you please post complete code example on http://codepen.io/pen/ or some other frontend testing site? I think something else is interfering with closing.

Comment: @zveljkovic Hey! check it http://codepen.io/elmucho/pen/eZMPPv :) thank you! and its bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your code are:

1. You have put modal code inside some other element and not directly in body as per directons on [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
2. You have resized your modal-body and modal-content so it is taking whole screen. Modals have a layer that occupies whole screen (modal-backdrop class) and above it they display the modal. This modal-backdrop class closes the modal when it receives the click but it can't do that now as it is covered by the modal dialog.

I think you may have wanted to have overlay over some element. Take a look at [Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/zveljkovic/pen/YqaRwM)

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="overlay">Flower, Plants, Herbs, Trees.,Flower, Plants, Herbs, Trees,Flower, Plants, Herbs, Trees,Flower, Plants, Herbs, Trees,</div>
</div>
.parent{
  background:green;
  position: fixed;
}

.content{
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
}

.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```